# Rubyで今月の末日を取得する方法について

Tags: ruby

現在このようなコードにしています。

`Date.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, -1).day`

もっとスマートに書けるんじゃないかと思うんですが、、、、

他に書き方があれば教えて下さい。

もっと言うと、「今日は末日かどうか」の判定を行うために使っています。
これに適した方法があればそちらも教えてくださると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1):

これはRubyなので、他に書き方があるはずですが`Date.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, -1).day`の書き方は結構読みやすいし、とても[人気のある](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14120721/1167750)書き方です。[別のアップローチ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16913606/1167750)もあるようですが、この場合の関数は元のアップローチより読みやすくないと私は思います。

また、Rails自体を使う場合は、[`end_of_month()`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/end_of_month)という関数もあると思います。

[yasuさんが説明した](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/23171/4129)ように、[ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport)のオプションもあります。そういえば、[`expanded_date`](https://rubygems.org/gems/expanded_date)というgemもあるようです。

`expanded_date`の例 ([Jonさんのスレに基づいた例](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95475#197276))：

```
require 'expanded_date'

d = Date.today
puts d.end_of_month.mday.to_s
```

出力は：

```
31
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSupport の `Date#at_end_of_month` (時刻なら `Time#at_end_of_month`) を利用する方法があります。(標準でスマートに書く方法は無いはず。)

```
require "active_support/all"

Date.today.at_end_of_month
# => Thu, 31 Mar 2016
```